# Is there a program that will parse sentence syntax?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am building an online course and want to add a function that can check spelling, grammar and syntax. I've found a few that claim to spot the first 2 but they are not very good. I typed in "That is you're coat." and 3 out of 4 said it was OK. Aside from this, my main problem is, for example, placing an adjective after a noun: e.g. "This is a tree green." None of the online checkers flagged this as being incorrect.

Am I chasing an impossible dream? Is the only way to learn how to correctly structure a sentence something that is only achievable by human to human training?

Comment: There are proprietary systems that claim to do as well as humans, but I don't see how they could be highly reliable.  Spoken and written English has rules, not mathematical laws, and, therefore, is not amenable to (a) scoring algorithm(s).  http://www.nytimes.com/2012/04/23/education/robo-readers-used-to-grade-test-essays.html

Comment: [Watson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_%28computer%29) from IBM? See the [DeepQA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DeepQA.svg) flowchart.

Comment: I parsed that as a noun–noun construct. In other words, if you can have a tee-off green for a green where one plays golf, why not a tree green for a green which happens to have tree on it?  Plus if you like trees green instead of brown, who could blame you? Really, there’s an entire field called Natural Language Processing, which is tied in to Computational Linguistics. There are several approaches to parsers. You can use a statistical approach that “learns” from a training set; humans do that.

Comment: Have you tried a more 'grammatically stringent' sample? The example is inappropriate to say the least.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. After reading the replies, media learning and human training appear to be better solutions. Thinking beyond "tree green" there are "code red" or "red code". I think I will leave the search for an automated solution alone for now.

Comment: To address only the question in the title, Language Log recently posted [an article](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9000) praising the Penn Treebank system of grammatical analysis of English. They link to several "[excellent](https://code.google.com/p/berkeleyparser/) [open-source](http://bllip.cs.brown.edu/resources.shtml) [parsers](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)". Here's one you can [try online](http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html).

Comment: Side note, spelling and syntax are components of grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Well, *this is a tree green* is weird but not definitively wrong. Presumably, you are trying to test with this believing that the correct sentence is *this is a green tree*.

But unfortunately, a grammar testing program cannot say the sentence is wrong. *Green* is also a noun and *tree* can be used adjectivally. I explain this to point out that it is definitively non-trivial to come up with a program that checks grammar, because there are many cases where something is grammatically possible but that you would want to cross out.

In terms of syntax, I don't fully understand what you mean by that term.

The only program I know that has a grammar checker in it is MS Word. There may be others.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with the systematic parsing of the English language. Innumerable sentences can be formed that are technically correct in form but are absolutely meaningless semantically, and automated semantic analysis is as of yet not accomplished (if it may be accomplished at all). Many everyday words double as proper nouns *(White House)*, a word can change its functional class based on usage and context *(putting **green**)*, homophones/homographs can clash *(to fish vs two fish)*, and many other scenarios all can get in the way of automated parsing.